# DoCmd.OutputTo Method: Excel format that opens for Access 2003 and 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, methods

The following code works on my Access 2010, but brings a compile error for users with Access 2003:

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "trndOTrpt", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint`

So I changed the output format to `acFormatXLS` (per [this website's suggestion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141534%28v=office.10%29.aspx)):

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "trndOTrpt", acFormatXLS, "", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint`

This opens on my Access 2010 (yet to test Access 2003) but only in the Excel 5.0/95 Workbook format.  Is there a way I can open this in the normal 97-03 .xls format in both versions of Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220433%28v=office.11%29.aspx) it turns out that Access 2003 had fewer argument options.  So my last 3 arguments, `"", ,acExportQualityPrint` created the problem, hence the full error dialog "Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."

I initially tried the TransferSpreadsheet method, but getting it to export to Excel *while* letting the user choose save name and destination was getting too cumbersome.  Reducing the arguments, OutputTo works great!